# ¿Cómo obtener la segunda palabra de cualquier string?

Tags: javascript

Necesito obtener la segunda palabra independientemente de que string sea. En resumen que sea reutilizable para cualquier string.

Como tal ya lo he logrado, pero cuando pruebo un string de solo dos palabras, se termina comiendo la ultima letra, por ejemplo:

- "hola como estas", su segunda palabra sería: "como"
- "hola mundo", sin embargo la segunda palabra es mundo, pero termina dandome: "mund"

Como ven se termina comiendo la ultima letra, ¿Cómo hago para que eso no suceda?

Anexo código :

```
function spaceSecondWord (text) {
  let firstSpace = text.indexOf(' ')
  let secondSpace = text.indexOf(' ', firstSpace +1)
  let secondWord = text.slice(firstSpace + 1, secondSpace)
  return secondWord
};
```

Comment: Más fácil vendría separas con un split los espacios y obtener el segundo elemento...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Siguiendo tu razonamiento, el problema es que cuando no hay un segundo espacio el indexOf te devuelve -1, entonces al hacer el slice le quita el último caracter, para eso podrías verificar si el resultado del indexOf es >=0 (quiere decir que encontró un " ") en ese caso haces el slice con ese final, en caso contrario el final sería el lenght (largo) del texto.

Ejemplo:

```js
function spaceSecondWord(text) {
  const firstSpace = text.indexOf(" ");
  const secondSpace = text.indexOf(" ", firstSpace + 1);
  let final = 0;

  if (secondSpace >= 0) {
    final = secondSpace;
  } else {
    final = text.length;
  }
  return text.slice(firstSpace + 1, final);
}

console.log(spaceSecondWord("Hola Second"))
console.log(spaceSecondWord("Hola Segunda Tercera Cuarta"))
```

También podrías hacer algo así:

```js
function spaceSecondWord(text) {
  return text.split(" ")[1];
}

console.log(spaceSecondWord("Hola Second"))
console.log(spaceSecondWord("Hola Segunda Tercera Cuarta"))
```

El método .split crea un array usando el separador que indiques como parámetro, en este caso utilizamos los espacios en blanco entre palabras, luego accedemos a la posición 1 del array resultando que es la segunda palabra y eso es lo que retornamos.

Link a documentación de split:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Comment: Gracias, teniendo en cuenta tu respuesta, puedo llegar a la conclusión de que el metodo al no encontrar un segundo espacio, sino un "" al final de la ultima palabra terminaba llevandose el ultimo caracter. Bien gracias por tu ayuda :)

Comment: Claro, el  indexOF al no encontrar el elemento devuelve -1 y el slice con -1 como segundo parametro te quitaba el último caracter del string resultante. Quedo a las órdenes.

Answer (score 0):

Para poder obtener la segunda palabra de cualquier string puedes hacerlo de esta manera.

```js
function spaceSecondWord (text) {
  if(text.includes(' ')){
    const [_, secondWord] = text.split(' ');
    return secondWord;
  }
  return text;
};
```